# Control whether XCode does minimal or full rebuild

Tags: xcode

In XCode (4.1) is it possible to control whether or not a particular build configuration does a minimal compilation or recompiles all files, when doing a Build?

Something like the "Enable minimal rebuild" switch in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode always does a minimal build - to do a full build you need to do a clean before the build.

Comment: So there is no way to specific that a particular configuration should always be cleaned first?

Comment: I don't think so - you could run xcodebuild -clean from the command line first. - also you would usually do build I used clean in OSX much less than I do with Visual Studio but YMMV  If you are looking for a totally clean build I would look into virtual machines and a fresh checkout from version control which requires much more than Xcode